# lapply and for loop to run a function through a list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, lapply

I have a list of data.frame and I'd like to run `cor.test` through each data.frame.
The `data.frame` has 8 columns, I would like to run `cor.test` for each of the first 7 columns against the 8th column.

I first set up the lists for storing the data

```
estimates = list()
pvalues = list()
```

Then here's the loop combining with `lapply`

```
for (i in 1:7){
  corr <- lapply(datalist, function(x) {cor.test(x[,i], x[,8], alternative="two-sided", method="spearman", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)}) 
  estimates= corr$estimate
  pvalues= corr$p.value
}
```

It ran without any errors but the `estimates` shows `NULL`

Which part of this went wrong? I used to run `for` loop over `cor.test` or run is with `lapply`, never put them together. I wonder if there's a solution to this or an alternative. Thank you.

Comment: **Self Promotion** If you don't mind, I have written up `get_var_corr` that does this. Currently available in the developer version of `manymodelr` available [here](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop).

Comment: I suppose you meant `alternative` instead of `alterantive` in your cor.test arguments.
Also you may want to increment you lists with :
estimates[[i]] <- corr$estimate ;
  pvalues[[i]] <- corr$p.value ;

Comment: The help (see ??cor.test) mention also "two.sided" as argument.

Comment: @cbo I don't see `alterantive`, it was `alternative`. I can't use increment with the `list` because there are ~500 `data.frame` in there and I have used `for (i in 1:7)` in the `for loop` already.

Comment: My bad, I copied an answer.
@Ronak Shah solution is the best any way.  Just to make my point : `i` in the for loop can be changed to `j` and then incremented with. The result (as for lapply, lapply being faster) will be the same than lapply : 2 lists with 500 elements in your case. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sapply`, showing with an example on `mtcars` where `cor.test` is performed with all columns against the first column.

```
lst <- list(mtcars, mtcars) 

lapply(lst, function(x) t(sapply(x[-8], function(y) {
   val <- cor.test(y, x[[8]], alternative ="two.sided", 
            method="spearman", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)
          c(val$estimate, pval = val$p.value)
})))

[[1]]
#            rho         pval
#mpg   0.7065968 6.176953e-06
#cyl  -0.8137890 1.520674e-08
#disp -0.7236643 2.906504e-06
#hp   -0.7515934 7.247490e-07
#drat  0.4474575 1.021422e-02
#wt   -0.5870162 4.163577e-04
#qsec  0.7915715 6.843882e-08
#am    0.1683451 3.566025e-01
#gear  0.2826617 1.168159e-01
#carb -0.6336948 9.977275e-05

#[[2]]
#            rho         pval
#mpg   0.7065968 6.176953e-06
#cyl  -0.8137890 1.520674e-08
#.....
```

This returns you list of two column matrix with `estimate` and `p.value` respectively.

Comment: The problem is that `mtcars` is a `data.frame` not a `list` of `data.frame`. So it didn't really help with my problem..

Comment: @Molly_K Updated the answer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Why I didn't think of this earlier. Two functions! Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: This answer uses the developer version of [manymodelr](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop) that I also wrote.

**EDIT**: You can map it to your list of data frames with `Map` or `lapply` for instance:

```
lst <- list(mtcars, mtcars) #Line copied and pasted from @Ronak Shah's answer
Map(function(x) manymodelr::get_var_corr(x, "mpg",get_all = TRUE,
                         alternative="two.sided",
                         method="spearman",
                         continuity=TRUE,exact=F),lst)
```

For a single `data.frame` object, we can use `get_var_corr`:

```
manymodelr::get_var_corr(mtcars, "mpg",get_all = TRUE,
                         alternative="two.sided",
                          method="spearman",
                          continuity=TRUE,exact=FALSE) 
   #    Comparison_Var Other_Var      p.value Correlation
   # 1             mpg       cyl 4.962301e-13  -0.9108013
   # 2             mpg      disp 6.731078e-13  -0.9088824
   # 3             mpg        hp 5.330559e-12  -0.8946646
   # 4             mpg      drat 5.369227e-05   0.6514555
   # 5             mpg        wt 1.553261e-11  -0.8864220
   # 6             mpg      qsec 7.042244e-03   0.4669358
   # 7             mpg        vs 6.176953e-06   0.7065968
   # 8             mpg        am 8.139885e-04   0.5620057
   # 9             mpg      gear 1.325942e-03   0.5427816
   # 10            mpg      carb 4.385340e-05  -0.6574976
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did have issues installing the package so I am not testing it at the moment. I used `devtools`  funciton `install_github`. I believe it was just some libraries are not updated for `manymodelr`

Comment: Sorry you had  issues installing the package, you can raise an issue on GitHub to let me know of the issues you faced. It does depend on a couple of packages although you can skip updating many of them as might be prompted. In any case, please feel free to use Ronak's answer to save time.

Answer (score 1):

purrr has some convenience functions could possibly make this operation a little more simple (although its debatable whether this is actually simpler than the Map/lapply way). Using Ronak's example list `lst`:

```
library(purrr)

lst <- list(mtcars, mtcars) 

map2(map(lst, ~.[-8]), map(lst, 8), ~
       map(.x, cor.test, y = .y, 
            alternative = "two.sided", 
            method = "spearman", 
            exact = FALSE, 
            continuity = TRUE) %>% 
       map_dfr(extract, c('estimate', 'p.value'), .id = 'var'))

# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#    var   estimate      p.value
#    <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1 mpg      0.707 0.00000618  
#  2 cyl     -0.814 0.0000000152
#  3 disp    -0.724 0.00000291  
#  4 hp      -0.752 0.000000725 
#  5 drat     0.447 0.0102      
#  6 wt      -0.587 0.000416    
#  7 qsec     0.792 0.0000000684
#  8 am       0.168 0.357       
#  9 gear     0.283 0.117       
# 10 carb    -0.634 0.0000998   
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 10 x 3
#    var   estimate      p.value
#    <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1 mpg      0.707 0.00000618  
#  2 cyl     -0.814 0.0000000152
#  3 disp    -0.724 0.00000291  
#  4 hp      -0.752 0.000000725 
#  5 drat     0.447 0.0102      
#  6 wt      -0.587 0.000416    
#  7 qsec     0.792 0.0000000684
#  8 am       0.168 0.357       
#  9 gear     0.283 0.117       
# 10 carb    -0.634 0.0000998
```